# Filter "own members" with BindingFlags

Tags: c#, properties, bindingflags

I got the following code :

```
public class PluginShape : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    #region Implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}

public class SpeedGenerator : PluginShape
{
    private int _SpeedValue;
    public int SpeedValue
    {
        get { return _SpeedValue; }
        set
        {
            _SpeedValue = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SpeedValue");
        }
    }

    public SpeedGenerator()
    {
        Name = "DefaultName";
    }
}
```

Then I'd like to filter the properties so that I only get the SpeedValue property.
I thought the following code will be ok, but it doesn't work :

```
var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
var filteredProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

in "props" I got both SpeedValue and Name properties but in "filteredProps" I got nothing...
Any help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx),

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or BindingFlags.Static in order to get a return.
>
> Specify BindingFlags.Public to include public properties in the search.

Thus, the following should do what you want:

```
var filteredProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: ok, I didnt understand how it works, that works, thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Once you start passing `BindingFlags`, you need to specify exactly what you want.

Add `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public`.

Comment: I tried var filteredProps = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance); and the list is empty too

Comment: Tries with "BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public" and I got my 2 properties, no filtering is done

Comment: You still want `DeclaredOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a custom Attribute for properties you'd like to use and query on those. I used this way to only have certain properties being displayed in as ListView Properties.

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
 public class ClassAttribute : Attribute
 {
   public String PropertyName;
   public String PropertyDescription;
 }
// Property declaration
[ClassAttribute(PropertyName = "Name", PropertyDescription = "Name")]
public String Name { get; private set; }

// Enumeration
  IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos = t.GetProperties();
  foreach (PropertyInfo PropertyInfo in PropertyInfos)
  {
    if (PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).Count() > 0)
    {
      PropertyInfo info = t.GetProperty(PropertyInfo.Name);
     }
   }
```